# Mysqldump doesn't export all databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysqldump to export my databases like that:

```
mysqldump.exe -u myuser --password=mypassword -A -R --events --triggers --single-transaction > "E:\my_folder\myfile.sql"
```

Expected behavior is to see all my databases imported after I import the .sql file in my new sql server. However I only see one of two. How can I resolve this?

Comment: try to load th sql file into mysql workbench and see if he finds something

Comment: Does `myuser` have privilege to both databases?

Comment: I added the sql file using Workbench but the result is the same.

Comment: Also, I am running this as root, I replaced it with myuser just for this post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with editing the script, including `--all-databases`